# Map only on element of a one to many relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mapping, restkit

I'm stuck with the following problem. I have a relationships one_to_many between a `Event` and `Comment`. One `Event` can have many `Comment` but a `Comment` has belongs_to only one `Event`.

Until here, everything is fine. Now, when I'm adding a comment, I would like to map only this new comment. That means I'm using my relationship from `Comment` to `Moment`.

I have some troubles with the mapping that I'm not able to solve. My error is at the end of this post after all the description.

I'm receiving this JSON:

```
"comment": {
    "id": 17,
    "commentable_id": 12,
    "commentable_type": "Moment",
    "content": "That's it ! ",
    "created_at": "2014-06-20T18:17:42Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-06-20T18:17:42Z",
    "user_id": 1,
    "creator": {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "firstname": "Bobby",
        "lastname": "Stouket",
        "gender": 0,
        "created_at": "2014-04-06T17:48:11Z",
        "updated_at": "2014-06-20T18:17:26Z"
    }
}
```

Here is my comment mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *commentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Comment" inManagedObjectStore:store];
commentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"commentId"];
[commentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"id" : @"commentId",
                                                     @"updated_at": @"updatedAt",
                                                     @"created_at": @"createdAt",
                                                     @"user_id": @"userId",
                                                     @"commentable_id": @"commentableId",
                                                     @"commentable_type": @"commentableType",
                                                     @"content": @"content"
                                                     }];

RKEntityMapping *userCreatorMapping = [APICallUser RKGetUserMappingOnlyWithAvatarForManagedObjectStore:store];
[commentMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"creator" connectedBy:@{@"userId": @"userId"}];
[commentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"creator"
                                                                              toKeyPath:@"creator"
                                                                            withMapping:userCreatorMapping]];
```

Here is my code for my moment mapping (with the association with comments which is working) :

```
RKEntityMapping *momentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Moment" inManagedObjectStore:store];
momentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"momentId"];
[momentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                          @"id" : @"momentId",
                                                          @"creator.id" : @"creatorId",
                                                          @"created_at" : @"createdAt",
                                                          @"updated_at" : @"updatedAt"
                                                          }];

RKEntityMapping *commentMapping = [APICallComment RKGetCommentMappingForManagedObjectStore:store];
[commentMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"moment" connectedBy:@{@"commentableId":@"momentId"}];
[momentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"comments"
                                                                              toKeyPath:@"comments"
                                                                            withMapping:commentMapping]];
```

There is one more thing to know is that a comment can be on a moment or on a photo. According to my JSON, I don't think I need an `RKDynamicMapping` but I'm not sure.

Here is the code when I'm using my mapping. The request is send successfully and I receive the JSON written before.

```
KEntityMapping *commentMapping = [APICallComment RKGetCommentMappingForManagedObjectStore:self.appDelegate.managedObjectStore];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:commentMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                   pathPattern:APICallCommentCreateCommentsRouteName
                                                                                       keyPath:@"comment"
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[session.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
//session.objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType=RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

> Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched." UserInfo=0xb8a9150 {DetailedErrors=(), NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: comments, device, devices
>   The representation inputted to the mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the following key paths: comment
>   This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings., NSLocalizedDescription=No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched., keyPath=null}

**Edit:**
Here is the result of the code line `session.objectManager.requestDescriptor`. It's really weird. I can see only 1 object in the `NSArray`. When I print it I can read:

```
Printing description of $1:
<__NSArrayI 0xbd61010>(
<RKRequestDescriptor: 0xbd12bb0 method=(POST) objectClass=BasicLocation rootKeyPath=position :      <RKObjectMapping:0xbd40b70 objectClass=NSMutableDictionary propertyMappings=(
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0xbd545d0 latitude => lat>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0xbd58430 longitude => lng>"
)>>
)
```

Nowhere I've written that `position`should be the rootKeyPath and my other attributes are not here (content, commentableType, userId, createdAt, updatedAt, commentId).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You show JSON for comment, but not moment - show that. The log message indicates that the code you show isn't the code you have - the key paths don't match (or you are simply failing to add a response descriptor after creating it). Consider using multiple response descriptors to separate out your 'creator' mapping processing...

Comment: The JSON is what I receive after the creation of a new comment. There is no JSON for moment here. The only place where there is an `comments` association is from my moment mapping but I'm not using it. Then I'm lost. I'm not familiar with multiple response descriptors yet.

Answer (score 1):

You create:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:commentMapping
                                                                                    method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                               pathPattern:APICallCommentCreateCommentsRouteName
                                                                                   keyPath:@"comment"
                                                                               statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

but you can't ever add it to the object manager, because it only understands `comments, device, devices`.

That would seem to be your main issue.

You wouldn't usually do this:

```
[commentMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"creator" connectedBy:@{@"userId": @"userId"}];
[commentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"creator"
                                                                          toKeyPath:@"creator"
                                                                        withMapping:userCreatorMapping]];
```

because you are supplying 2 different mappings for exactly the same content and relationship where you only need one because the user information is nested inside the comment information. So, you can remove the foreign key mapping (`addConnectionForRelationship:`).

Comment: I thought that `addConnectionForRelationship` was saying which attributes use for the matching/linking between models. If I'm only using `addPropertyMapping`, how `Restkit` will know which attributes use ?

Comment: `addConnectionForRelationship` is used for foreign key mapping, so where the data isn't nested. If it's nested then the mapping you supply to `relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:` provides the unique identity to match to and the nesting provides the connection context.

Comment: My mistake, it's obviously `[userCreatorMapping addConnectionForRelationship..]`.

Comment: But why can't I add my descriptor to the object manager ? Then, how does my object manager understand `comment` ? I'm still a bit lost with those mappings.

Comment: You can and you should add the response descriptor, but it seems that you haven't, because the object manager only understands comments, device and devices -- but not `comment`

Comment: It's really weird. I've added the code just after my descriptor where I'm adding it to the object manager. I think my mapping is good (at least a part) because I can receive several comments in the same time (with `RKPaginator`).

Comment: Are you calling a POST or a GET then?

Comment: I'm calling a POST for my create. In my database, the creation is working. I have the callback (First JSON chain).

Comment: And then you call GET later? Because your response descriptor for `comment` is specific for a POST and won't be used for a GET.

Comment: Ok. Such a stupid problem : my path pattern ! I was using `APICallCommentCreateCommentsRouteName` instead of `APICallCommentCreateCommentsPattern`.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping was good but the mistake comes from here:

```
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:commentMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:HERE
                                            keyPath:@"comment"
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

I didn't write the path pattern. This variable changed and everything works perfectly.